# Can't access an SD card plugged in through a USB adapter

Tags: hard-disk, usb-drive

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9M7V.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqyU0.jpg)

The Disks utility doesn't allow formatting the disk. I, also, tried running `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`, but it returned `cannot open /dev/sda: No medium found`.

I tried it with two different adapters, two different SD cards and two different USB ports, so the problem is not likely to be with those devices.

Interestingly, one SD card *was* recognized at first, but, after I tried flashing some .iso to it, it immediately vanished from the view of my machine.

`lsblk` lists `sda` only when run with the `-a` flag, which means that the `sda` is "an empty device" as per `man lsblk`. I don't really know how to interpret that.

Here's the full output of `sudo lsblk -a`:

```
sda           8:0    1         0 disk 
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p4 259:2    0 476,4G  0 part /
```

*P.S. Sorry for not embedding the images correctly. Due to some server problems, I wasn't able to do that.*

Comment: So, are you sure it is `/dev/sda`? Not `/dev/sdb` or `c` or further? What does `lsblk` give?

Comment: @LjmDullaart Hey, thanks for responding! It's what the Disks app says (see image 1). Also, `lsblk` returns `/dev/sda`. I've added the full output of `lsblk` to the post